# Does SonarQube provide a feature to take the diff with old files to review how we fixed a particular issue?

Tags: sonarqube

Does SonarQube provide a feature to take the diff with old files to review how we fixed a particular issue?

Like I built my project , and sonar is saying all the blocker is fixed. My manager want to review the code from the sonar and compare the files with the original one. Is there I can do in sonar?

I am using sonarqube 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can't do this in SonarQube itself. It pretty much boils down to SonarQube not really being a code versioning tool, so code history is not kept in database. The [History and Events](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/History+and+Events) documentation gives a few insight into what's happening:

> when you run a new analysis of your project, some data that was previously available is cleaned out of the database. For example the source code of the previous analysis, measures at directory and file levels, and so on are automatically be removed at the end of a new analysis.

If your goal is to view the diff that fixed an issue, then in SonarQube you could leverage the [SCM information](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Component+Viewer#ComponentViewer-Layout) shown next to the code. Clicking on it will give you the commit hash, which you can then pass to your SCM tool to view the actual code diff.

Comment: Thanks. That was a great help. But don't you think as code review is the most important for any kind of profiling tool, its a good idea to add this feature as it helps the code review more smoother, instead of finding the hashtag and switching the tool?

Comment: Profiling tools and code review tools are completely different tools in my opinion, and SonarQube is clearly not meant to be used for code review (there are [much better solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_code_review)). But that's an entirely separate discussion.